# Haproxy custom error pages only work sometimes

Tags: haproxy

I have Apache operating as a reverse proxy which redirects to a HaProxy server set up which load balances between two backend servers using cookies.  It's not elegant but everything works fine ...

The backend servers run a web application which uses basic authentication (it's all it offers) and if users enter the wrong login details then the backend app times out.  As a result HaProxy shows a 504 error.

To help my users log in properly I've put together custom error pages for the 504 error as well as 503 and 502 and these display *some* of the time.  Other times a standard error page is shown in the browser which bears no relation to the ones that I've defined and are nothing like the default ones that come with HaProxy (e.g. /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http etc).

The error pages are defined in the global section as well as in each backend section.  They are small ~1800 bytes and are valid html

It appears that the browsers read the HTTP response and some of the time display their own version of the page.  They then also cache the error page so that when the user tries to access the page again the error page is served up again instead of pulling the page and showing the basic authentication login box.  The only way to get the login box to reappear is to close the browser, reopen it and then navigate back to the login url.

I'd forgotten about the Apache reverse proxy sat in front of my HaProxy servers and wondered if my backend server was sending a 503 error which was then getting caught by HaProxy and this was, in turn, getting caught by Apache.  To test this I changed my custom HaProxy error pages so that they return a 200 OK status to Apache.  It worked once, but then defaulted back to the standard message:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Each error file looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<head>
<title>Username and/or password error</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Some explanatory text ...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What is going on here ?  How do I get my custom error page to appear consistently ?  And for then not to be cached in the users browser ?

I've reloaded and restarted haproxy having edited haproxy.cfg numerous times.  Here's my haproxy.cfg file:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  30000
    timeout server  30000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502-custom.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-custom.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504-custom.http

frontend http_front
   bind *:8085
   stats uri /haproxy?stats

   acl is_S0 hdr_sub(cookie) S0
   acl is_S1 hdr_sub(cookie) S1

   use_backend backend_S0 if is_S0
   use_backend backend_S1 if is_S1
   default_backend backend_S0

backend backend_S0
   server Public0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 check
   errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502-custom.http
   errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-custom.http
   errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504-custom.http


backend backend_S1
   server Public1 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8080 check
   errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502-custom.http
   errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503-custom.http
   errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504-custom.http
```

Comment: It is common to add a few lines of `<!-- padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->` to the bottom of your error pages but it's not obvious why you seem to be experiencing inconsistent behavior with *static* error files.  Do you have some screen shots of the errors?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I've added a bunch of comments as you suggested but it's made no difference.  I've also added four paragraphs of text via a Lorum Ipsum generator in case it was down to the size of the page returned but that's made no difference either ....

Comment: Review your log files.  Correlate what you see in the browser with what HAProxy is logging.  Pay particular attention to the "Session State at Disconnection" mentioned in the HAProxy documentation.